# Redirect to show in another controller (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a form that allows the user to Post in the a group Show method.  Upon posting, I want to redirect to the same page showing the new post.  I'm using the following, but I get the error below.  I'm not sure why @group is nil, because I've defined it in the show of my group controller.

No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
for
redirect_to group_path(@group)

```
<%=form_for([@post]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class = "field">
      <%= f.label :event_name %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:event_id, @events, :id, :title) %>
    </div>
    <div class = "field">
      <%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: "New Post..." %>
    </div>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%=f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<%end%>


class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if @post = Post.create(post_params)
      flash[:success] = "Post Created!"
      redirect_to group_path(@group)
    else
      redirect_to group_url
      flash[:alert] = "Sorry - Post not created."
    end
  end
end


  def show
    @event = @group.events.build
    @post = Post.new
    @events = @group.events.includes(:posts)
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your create action you attempt to use the @group instance variable. You haven't defined it in the create action so you'll need to create it there if you want to use it. Since the call to create is in a separate request cycle the instance variables you defined in the show action are not available.

Update:
To get the group if you have an event_id and event belongs_to :group you would do:

```
event = Event.find(event_id)
@group = event.group
```

Comment: How would I find the @group... my form passes event_id only, not group_id.  A Group has_many events in my app.

Comment: If the event has a belongs_to :group then you can get the group from the event.

Answer (score 2):

Set `@group` in `create` action. You have not assigned any value to `@group` there which is why you are getting error.

**EDIT**

As per your comment `A Group has_many events` so you can find the group as below:

```
@group = Event.find(params[:event_id]).group
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried to do this as well, like so, but no dice: @group = Group.find(params[:event_id])